# Create a file in SQL Server 2008 R2 and convert it to image datatype without writing it to disk?

Tags: sql, pdf, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am currently generating PDF reports by building the pdf as plaintext (based on this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Miscellaneous/creatingapdffromastoredprocedure/1104/ )

It builds the body in plaintext then saves it to a folder using `sp_OACreate` with the `.pdf` extension. It is actually faster than SSRS in this case; we are generating 5k-100k pdfs (historical transaction data for our customers' customers)

I then have to load these files into an `image` column so the clients can access their report through the software.

Is there a way to generate the file and convert it to an `image` without writing it to the disk and then reloading it?

- I cannot change the software, the file must be presented to the client when they click the button in the interface.
- I cannot change the database. I have these files saved as `image` datatypes. I cannot change this to any other data type. The files are all less than 20k in size.
- I cannot implement filestream due to PCI Compliance security reasons.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server you can program stored procedure on `.NET` language (C#, VB...) Inside `.NET assembly` write code for generating PDF reports. Then you only have to execute this stored procedure and save it result to database table.

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this in T-SQL

Comment: I've looked T-SQL solution for generating PDF reports (your link). Have a look at this line of code `INSERT INTO #pdf (code) (SELECT code FROM #xref)` in the end of stored procedure body. So, temp table #pdf contains all data, which you need, you have to save it to table column.